# Aligning image with text in a table

Tags: html, image, text, html-table, alignment

I'm trying to align an image with text in a table such that the image is aligned to the **bottom** of the text.

The current code I have for the table is:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>  
      <tr>  
        <th><h4><img src="image.png" />Title1</h4></th>  
        <th><h4><img src="image2.png" />Title2</h4></th>  
      </tr>  
    </thead>  
    <tbody>  
      <tr>  
        <td>Subtitle1</td>
        <td>Subtitle2</td>
      </tr>  
      <tr>  
        <td>Subtitle1</td>
        <td>Subtitle2</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

It currently looks like this: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gm319.png]

How do I make the image align to the bottom of the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will do it...

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>  
    <tr>  
      <th><h4><img src="image.png" style="vertical-align: text-bottom;" />Title1</h4></th>  
      <th><h4><img src="image2.png" style="vertical-align: text-bottom;" />Title2</h4></th>  
    </tr>  
  </thead>  
  <tbody>  
    <tr>  
      <td>Subtitle1</td>
      <td>Subtitle2</td>
    </tr>  
    <tr>  
      <td>Subtitle1</td>
      <td>Subtitle2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

It uses the style attribute -VERTICAL-ALIGN and assigns the value TEXT-BOTTOM

Comment: It made it a little better, but it's still not aligned to the very bottom: [http://i.imgur.com/MlrWp.png](http://i.imgur.com/MlrWp.png)

Comment: You can try BOTTOM as opposed to TEXT-BOTTOM...
Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ie/ms531179(v=vs.85).aspx